# Trying to use appendTo() to push dives to one part of a page, after a first appendTo() is done.

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a game where the user has 4 pictures to choose from, once a character is selected the other 3 images are pushed to a new section where the user then selects a character to fight. What should happen next is that once that character is selected from the enemy select area it would then be pushed to a new area where it would fight the original character that is selected.

Currently I can get the character select and the staging area for the enemy to fight to work. It seems however once an enemy is selected it just breaks the whole thing and pushes all the characters to the enemy staging area, I am having trouble figuring out how to make it work so once an enemy is in the staging area that it would then be able to be selected and then pushed to the fighting area. Thanks for the help, heres what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var char ="";
isChosen = false;
ifattacker = false;
```

$(".defender").click(function(){ //trying to figure out how to select a character

```
    if (isChosen) return;

    ($(".frodo").on("click",function(){
        $(".gandalf").appendTo(".enemy-select1");
        $(".balrog").appendTo(".enemy-select2").addClass("attacker");
        $(".sauron").appendTo(".enemy-select3").addClass("attacker");
    }));

    ($(".gandalf").on("click",function(){
        $(".frodo").appendTo(".enemy-select1");
        $(".balrog").appendTo(".enemy-select2");
        $(".sauron").appendTo(".enemy-select3");
    }));

    ($(".balrog").on("click",function(){
        $(".frodo").appendTo(".enemy-select1");
        $(".gandalf").appendTo(".enemy-select2");
        $(".sauron").appendTo(".enemy-select3");
    }));

    ($(".sauron").on("click",function(){
        $(".frodo").appendTo(".enemy-select1");
        $(".gandalf").appendTo(".enemy-select2");
        $(".balrog").appendTo(".enemy-select3");
    }));

}); // end characters click

$("attacker").click(function(){

isChosen = true;

($(".gandalf").on("click",function(){
        $(".gandalf").appendTo(".attack")
    }));

});


}); // end document ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm noticing two things, one of which I believe is the root cause of the issue, the other a simple syntax error.

**1.** You are binding a click event to Gandalf when `.defender` is clicked. When `.attacker` is clicked, you're binding *another* event to Gandalf. This does not replace the original event, it *adds* to it, and so clicking Gandalf will re-fire the initial event. What you may wish to do is:

```
$(".attacker").click(function(){

    isChosen = true;
    //Unbind the previous click event using .off() before binding new event
    $(".gandalf").off().on("click",function(){
        $(".gandalf").appendTo(".attack")
    });

});
```

**2.** In the above snippet, I added a `.` to your `attacker` selector, because I assume you wanted to bind that to the click of the attacker class. Should be `$(".attacker")`.

Comment: Awesome! that worked thanks, i had no idea about that off() function....really appreciate the help

Comment: actually, now im running into an issue where the character just goes directly into the fight section if i click on it...any idea on that one?

Comment: If you want to put an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) I can try to debug it for you.